# python 2.8 - image texture stretch versus repeat

Tags: python, texturing, uv, image

In Blender/Python 2.8, I have added an image texture to an object.  The object is very wide which causes the image texture to stretch whereas I would like it to repeat.

The [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ShaderNodeTexImage.html) (under "extension") seems to suggest that the default setting is for the texture to repeat rather than to stretch.  I would assume that because I am using the default that the texture would repeat rather than stretch.

Any suggestions as to how to prevent stretch in my code would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

```
def obj_texture(objname, filename, mat_name):
    materials = bpy.data.materials
    material = materials.get(mat_name)
    if not material:
        material = materials.new(mat_name)
    clear_material(material)
    material.use_nodes = True
    nodes = material.node_tree.nodes
    links = material.node_tree.links
    output = nodes.new(type = 'ShaderNodeOutputMaterial' )
    diffuse = nodes.new(type = 'ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse' )
    path=TextureFolder+filename
    imgTex = bpy.data.images.load(path)
    node_texture = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeTexImage')
    node_texture.image = imgTex
    node_texture.location = 0,200

    tex_coord = nodes.new(type = 'ShaderNodeTexCoord') #NEW CODE @RJG

    links = material.node_tree.links

    link=links.new(tex_coord.outputs["Generated"], node_texture.inputs["Vector"]) #NEW CODE @RJG

    link = links.new(node_texture.outputs[0], nodes.get('Diffuse BSDF').inputs[0])
    link = links.new( diffuse.outputs['BSDF'], output.inputs['Surface'] )
    obj=bpy.data.objects[objname]
    obj.active_material=material
```

Comment: I'd say you've essentially answered your own question. If you test your script you'll set that the *Extension* is set to repeat. If you want anything other than repeat you'll have to add `node_texture.extension = "CLIP"` or `node_texture.extension = "EXTEND"` but by default it will already by `REPEAT`.

Comment: @rjg But when I run it, the texture doesn't repeat, it stretches.

Comment: That will likely be because of your texture coordinates. You need to input UV or generated coordinates through a Texture Coordinate node to your Image Texture node

Comment: @rjg Adding the texture coordinate node, it is not obvious how the sockets line up; experimenting with various connections does not fix the problem ... screenshot here:  https://imgur.com/a/aNLETIx

Comment: Let's say you've created a new Texture Coordinate node in your script `tex_coord = nodes.new(type = 'ShaderNodeTexCoord')` , then you can `links.new(tex_coord.outputs["Generated"], node_texture.inputs["Vector"])` or `links.new(tex_coord.outputs["UV"], node_texture.inputs["Vector"])`

Comment: @rjg thanks!  I tried this - the result looks slightly different but still is stretched (https://imgur.com/a/bpvaYRh).  I have edited my script above to show the changes in case I missed something.  Thoughts?

Comment: did you unwrap your mesh so that it has proper UV coordinates?

Comment: um...no.  Guess I will start a new thread on that...

Comment: @rjg UV coordinates don't have an effect when using "Generated" texture coordinates, the point of which is to avoid having to unwrap meshes or otherwise assign UV coordinates.

Comment: @kheetor correct. He didn't specify whether he uses UV or Generated which is why I described both ways.

Comment: @rjg well his stretch issues are because of non-uniform object scale, neither of those are going to fix them.

Comment: @kheetor I didn't know that at the time. He posted the new question 1 hour ago.

Comment: @rjg I know, just shame that all that unwrapping talk got him making more threads and obfuscated the issue.

Comment: The object is stretched in python; immediately before applying the texture the scaling reads (1,1,1).  The image appears stretched even though there appears to be no scaling going on.  After applying the texture, the code doesn't rescale the object in question. So it would seem that the non-uniform object scale wouldn't be the issue unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a *Texture Coordinate* node and connect it to the *Image Texture* node. This is necessary to provide a mapping for the 2D image onto the 3D model.

The *Texture Coordinate* node is created using:

```
tex_coord = nodes.new(type = 'ShaderNodeTexCoord')
```

Then link the appropriate coordinate type to your image texture. Usually this would be either *UV* for the coordinates created through UV unwrapping of your mesh or *Generated* for the automatically generated coordinates. Depending on what you choose, you'll have to use one of the following options to connect the sockets.

```
links.new(tex_coord.outputs["UV"], node_texture.inputs["Vector"])
```

or

```
links.new(tex_coord.outputs["Generated"], node_texture.inputs["Vector"])
```

The *Extension* of the *Image Texture* node doesn't have to be changed, since it is set to *Repeat* by default, just like the documentation says.

Comment: thanks!  Do you have any suggestions as to a good place to learn about unwrapping a mesh and whatever other precursors are necessary?

Comment: @vndep for the very basic idea see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM